# Can't hide popup when clicked on draggable object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable

So here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/C4CcA/4/

The problem is that I am not able to hide the yellow popup when I click on div2 (because it is draggable). If I can catch the event triggered when clicked on div2 will be much better.

Any work around?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724743/using-jquery-setting-draggable-on-an-element-prevents-blur-from-firing-when-you

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
$("#div2").draggable().click(function(ev) {
    if (ev.target === this) {
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

otherwise you can use `delegate` or `on`

Comment: what this does, is it calls a focus event on div2 when it is clicked and not when the textbox is clicked

Answer (score 0):

A small work around

```
$(function(){
    $("#div2").draggable();

    $("#txtbox").click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("#colorpicker").show();
    });

    $("#txtbox").blur(function(){
        $("#colorpicker").hide();
    });

    $('#div2').click(function() {
       $("#colorpicker").hide();
    });
});
```

I am just stopping the propagation to div2 when you click on textbox. Otherwise it will hide the colorbox again.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with mouseDown event

```
$("#div2").mousedown(function() {
    $("#colorpicker").hide();
    $("#txtbox").blur();
});
```

The fiddle is here - http://jsfiddle.net/C4CcA/19/