# Why does a jQuery UI draggable interfere with Knockout JS data binding?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I'd like to understand why making a containing div into a jQuery UI draggable in the following code changes the behaviour of the Knockout JS data binding.

In the first div (which is draggable) making a change to the text in the input box and immediately clicking Save doesn't result in the change being reflected in the observable. In the second div (which is not draggable) the change is reflected in the observable:

```html
<div id='draggable'>
    <h3>Draggable</h3>
    <input data-bind='value: detail'></input>
    <span data-bind='click: saveEdit'>Save</span>
</div>
<div id='fixed'>
    <h3>Fixed</h3>
    <input data-bind='value: detail'></input>
    <span data-bind='click: saveEdit'>Save</span>
</div>
```

With the following supporting Javascript:

```js
VM = {
    detail: ko.observable('Cat'),
    saveEdit: function(){
        alert(this.detail()); 
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable();
    ko.applyBindings(VM);
});
```

You can see the code in action at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NLzg2/

If you change the text in the draggable input box to Cath and click 'Save' the alert shows 'Cat'. However if you do the same in the fixed input box the alert shows 'Cath'. So in the second case Knockout has detected a change of value and in the first case it hasn't.

I know that I can achieve the desired effect by making use of the Knockout valueUpdate binding to force it to update the bound observable after each keypress. Like so:

```html
<input data-bind='value: detail, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"'></input>
```

I also know that if I change the <span> to a <button> I get the behaviour that I expected.

What I would like to understand is why this is happening, and how I can achieve the effect I want (i.e. a draggable and have normal Knockout value binding on the elements within it) without having to pepper my code with valueUpdate bindings or use a button to skirt around the issue.

Comment: seems jQuery UI draggable is affecting the blur event, which is why it works if you specify the `valueUpdate` binding.  There's a similar bug described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724743/using-jquery-setting-draggable-on-an-element-prevents-blur-from-firing-when-you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `draggable` plugin captures the mouse in order to provide its functionality. So you when click on your `span` the plugin handles the click event and knockout does not get notified.

It works when you are using a `button` because buttons are excluded from the effect of the draggable plugin.

So you need to exclude your `span` from the `draggable` plugin with using the [cancel option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel) for example with a help of a marker class:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({cancel: "input,textarea,button,select,option,.save"});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wppwF/).